# How to pass an overloaded function pointer as an argument without resolving (C++03)

Tags: c++, function, templates, pointers

I would like to apply an overloaded function to all elements of a struct like so: (The code below will not compile)

```
#include <iostream>

typedef struct {
  float float_val;
  int int_val;
} NodeStatus;

template<typename T>
void ApplyToFields(NodeStatus *ns1, NodeStatus *ns2, void (*func)(T, T)) {
  func(ns1->float_val, ns2->float_val);
  func(ns1->int_val, ns2->int_val);
}

template<typename T>
void add_print(T a, T b) {
  std::cout << b + a << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void sub_print(T a, T b) {
  std::cout << b - a << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  NodeStatus ns1, ns2;
  ns1.float_val = 2.3;
  ns2.float_val = 25.3;
  ns1.int_val = 2;
  ns2.int_val = 20;
  ApplyToFields(&ns1, &ns2, add_print);
  ApplyToFields(&ns1, &ns2, sub_print);
}
```

I am new to C++ coming from C. After some research I realize that passing a function pointer is probably not the correct way to do this in C++. I am interested in the best way to accomplish the same purpose as opposed to the literal question I posed which may be impossible. Solutions adhering to C++03 would be ideal. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a function object wrapping your function template (or replacing it):

```
struct add_printer {
    template<typename T>
    void operator()(T a, T b) const {
        add_print(a, b);
    }
};
```

And then use it like this:

```
ApplyToFields(&ns1, &ns2, add_printer());
```

This will delay overload resolution until `add_printer`'s `operator()` is actually instantiated when it is used in `ApplyToFields`.

In C++14, you could use a polymorphic lambda:
`[](auto a, auto b) { add_print(a, b); }`
which, unlike the function object, can be defined almost anywhere, not just at namespace scope.

Answer (score 1):

With your code, you have to specify which overload you want:

```
ApplyToFields(&ns1, &ns2, add_print<float>);
ApplyToFields(&ns1, &ns2, sub_print<int>);
```

or

```
ApplyToFields<float>(&ns1, &ns2, add_print);
ApplyToFields<int>(&ns1, &ns2, sub_print);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/62820163c7c490a3)

That you want is a generic functor

```
template<typename F>
void ApplyToFields(const NodeStatus &ns1, const NodeStatus &ns2, F func) {
  func(ns1.float_val, ns2.float_val);
  func(ns1.int_val, ns2.int_val);
}

struct add_print
{
    template<typename T>
    void operator() (T a, T b) {
        std::cout << b + a << std::endl;
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cdc038752bf3ec0d)

Comment: Thanks, I know that I can resolve the function signature when I pass it in as you described, but I want to use both the float and the int version inside of the `ApplyToFields` function. I don't want to resolve the overloading until inside of that function.

Comment: Yes, the generic functor is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!