# How to pass std::sort and similar overloaded functions to a function

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I need a function `apply(Function f, Container &c)` which would apply a given function to a range (container).

```
std::vector<int> a = {1, 5, 2, 4, 3};
apply(std::sort, a); // {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
apply(std::reverse, a); // {5, 4, 3, 2, 1}
```

This is a basic example of the behaviour I am looking for. Also, returning the value of the function (for example `std::max_element`) and variadic arguments (lambda comparators for sorting) would be nice bonuses.

Actually I can't even pass `std::sort` or `std::reverse` as a function to a function. What I tried is:

```
template<typename F, typename T>
void apply(const F &f, T &a) {
    f(a.begin(), a.end());
}
```

and:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
U apply(U (*f)(typename T::iterator, typename T::iterator), T &a) {
    return (*f)(a.begin(), a.end());
}
```

Both are giving me `apply(<unresolved overloaded function type>, std::vector<int>&)`.

So, is there a way to do it and what's the most modern way to do it?

Comment: * There's https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697180/template-function-as-a-template-argument but I think it only works if you know exactly the type.

Comment: • You can make a lambda function to wrap the sort function instead. Does that satisfy your requirement or "too verbose"?

Comment: Or equivalently a function object class [c++ - How to pass an overloaded function pointer as an argument without resolving (C++03) - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35759460/how-to-pass-an-overloaded-function-pointer-as-an-argument-without-resolving-c).

Comment: The problem is that `std::sort` isn't a function, it's a collection of multiple function templates. One approach is to specify a specific instantiation [like so](https://godbolt.org/z/dxzf75a81).

Comment: @NathanPierson Is that really okay? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68555771/5267751

Comment: Very peculiar! Good catch

Comment: Why? this seems redundant and dispensable. Ah, you want to type less on your keyboard!

Comment: @NathanPierson You can't even pick a specialization, because the standard [forbids the creation of a "pointer to function" for any standard library function or instantiation of a templated standard library function](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/requirements#namespace.std-6), except for so-called "addressable functions". This restriction necessary because many functions internally use `std::enable_if` or default parameters to control whether they participate in overload resolution.

Comment: I've closed the question as a duplicate. Based on this comment thread, it's not clear to me whether any of the answers on the target are correct, so you might want to look at the linked resources in these comments as well.

Comment: FWIW, there are range versions of algorithms now if that's where you were headed: `std::ranges::sort(a);`. You can, of course, use a namespace alias.